# Run a script if password is entered wrong 3 times at lock screen [OS X]

Tags: macos, passwords, lockscreen

I want to get my MacBook to automatically execute a shell script if the password at lock screen is entered wrong 3 times to restart the computer. Writing the script is easy enough, but how can I make it trigger automatically with a number of failed log-in attempts?

I'm using OS X 10.11.

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately not possible to make on Mac OS X as you cannot get access to the lock screen. This is made as a security measure so that third party apps cannot retrieve passwords or login information. Therefore, unfortunately, it's not possible to get any data from the lock screen including failed attempts or running scripts.

The closest you could get to achieving this has a script run at login. However that kind of defeats the purpose of what you want to do.

Hope that helps, Julian